# Ajuda para entender coordenadas e dimensionamento da SVG

Tags: svg

Estou tentando definir um icone.svg no sistema e algo deu errado: o ícone não aparece na tela... Acho que pode ser o sistema de coordenadas. Estou com dúvida em como redimensionar o tamanho das imagens e sobre o tal sistema de coordenadas.

Não entendi bem as propriedades `height`, `width` e `viewBox`.
O que acontece se usá-las juntas? E o que acontece se omitir `height` e `width`?

Seguem os códigos:

(o doc svg do icone *coracao.svg*)

```xml
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
    <symbol id="coracao">
      <path fill="red" d="M401.788,74.476c-63.492-82.432-188.446-33.792-188.446,49.92
            c0-83.712-124.962-132.356-188.463-49.92c-65.63,85.222-0.943,234.509,188.459,320.265
            C402.731,308.985,467.418,159.698,401.788,74.476z" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>

</svg>
```

(a div do doc HTML onde quero colocar o icone.svg com o tamanho de 50px 50px)

```xml
<div id="amei" title="amei">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <use xlink:href="coracao.svg#coracao" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Gostaria de uma explicação com detalhes, porque até agora essa duvida chata não foi sanada.

Comment: Não tenho tempo pra entrar em detalhes agora (até gostaria, mas tou meio atarefado) mas já adianto que pro seu caso vai ser algo assim: `<svg viewBox="0 0 430 430">` - se ninguem der uma resposta elaborada, pode ser que eu poste algo amanhã

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Bacco, gostaria! Bom trabalho enquanto isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, é bom entender que o SVG é praticamente um quadro infinito para se desenhar.

Você pode desenhar em qualquer X e Y positivo ou negativo (enquanto não estourar a capacidade numérica das coordenadas), sem precisar definir tamanho nenhum.

No sistema de coordenadas do SVG, o `X` vai aumentando para a direita, e o `Y` vai aumentando para baixo.

Assim, você pode desenhar um quadrado que vá de `10, 10` até `20, 20`, ou pode desenhar o mesmo quadrado de `60, 10` até `70,20`.

### A *viewport*

Com essa liberdade toda, foi necessário um mecanismo para definir qual é a parte do SVG que será exibida de fato, e este mecanismo é a `viewport`.

Basicamente a `viewport` é definida pelas coordenadas do canto superior esquerdo da janela, e a largura e altura.

Se você tiver um círculo que vá de `-100, -100` a `100, 100` e sua *viewport* for de `0,0` a `200,200`, você só verá o quadrante da direita embaixo do círculo, e ele não passará do centro da imagem gerada.

Círculo `-100, -100` a `100, 100`:

[image: original]

Viewport `0,0` a `200, 200` da imagem acima:

[image: Com viewport]

### A *viewbox*

A *viewbox* é uma transformação feita na *viewport*. Se pensarmos na *viewport* como a origem do que vai ser desenhado, a *viewbox* é o destino.

Por exemplo, se nossa *viewport* é de `0,0` a `10,10` e nossa *viewbox* é `0,0` a `100,100` o recorte original da imagem será ampliado `10x`.

Comment: o assunto é um bocado extenso, se for ver. Não prometo, mas talvez eu coloque mais detalhes no futuro. Se tiver alguma duvida mais especifica, ou coisa que não ficou clara para sua necessidade imediata, deixe um comentário.

Comment: Entendi! viewbox é um zoom in ou zoom out. O que define o tamanho original são height e width. O tamanho do campo onde é "desenhado" a SVG, caso não tenham sido definidas height e width, será ampliado conforme as coordenadas dos elementos necessitem. Então se desenho um <rect> de 100px de comprimento, o quadro SVG adotara uma width com o mesmo valor. E uso viewBox para definir o "tamanho" proporcional. Estou certo? De qualquer forma, muito obrigado @Bacco.

Comment: O viewport define o pedaço do "quadro infinito" que vai ser mostrado (como se recortasse esse pedaço retangular com uma tesoura). O viewbox pega esse pedaço recortado e coloca ele na imagem final (esticado, prensado, original etc).

Comment: Ok. Mas caso height e width sejam omitidos, o que define tais propriedades é o tamanho dos elementos <svg> que estão lá dentro. Certo?

Comment: Aí o que define o tamanho é o lugar onde você insere o svg. Usualmente ele se "ajeita" no espaço.

Comment: Mas ai vem a questão dos alinhamentos. Se puser o SVG num espaço de proporção diferente do original, tem outras configurações que determinam se ele vai ser cortado, se vai caber, etc. entao o ideal é manter ao menos a proporção do viewport. Se o viewport tem tamanho 200x100, num 300x150 fica bom, pq continua a relação 2:1 - ou no exemplo que eu dei, do coração, de viewport 430x430, num 50x50 é pra aparecer o coração inteiro.

Comment: Certo. Bem, de maneiro concisa: Qual o efeito caso não se defina as propriedades height e width?

Comment: como comentei, depende do espaço que vc coloca o svg - se mantiver a proporção, ele se ajeita. se a proporção estiver errada, depende de vários fatores, como alinhamento, e mais uma série de parâmetros do próprio SVG. O jeito tranquilo de trabalhar é ao menos manter a proporção.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51220/discussion-between-lucas-trino-and-bacco).